# Chip identification

Tags: identification

I have a small electronic device that seems to have suffered from a voltage surge or similar bad event (ESD?).

I think it is a DC/DC converter but I couldn't find anything with the markings that are hard to read/take a picture of: `W8BFZ`?

[image: PCB picture]

It has 6 pins, 1 bottom left, the 2 is visibly ground and the others are connected to external lump elements. The pin 5 seems to have exploded.

I found a similar device called MP2459 and the pinout matches (2=GND, 5=IN).

Can someone identify more precisely the chip ID?

Edit: forgot to post the corpse:

[image: aftermath of whatever event caused destruction]

Comment: Can you provide package dimensions?

Comment: I don't have tools to measure but I'm pretty sure the cap on the left is 0201. That should help gauge the size. Does that answer? Sorry I can't do better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Silergy Corp SY8120B1ABC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081220_Silergy-Corp-SY8120B1ABC_C88474.pdf) step down converter.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Silergy-Corp-SY8120B1ABC_C88474.html))